# How do I create a new Oracle schema?

Tags: oracle, schema, docker, oracle-xe, oracle-18c

I’m pretty familiar with Relational DBMS in general, but not with Oracle. I have Oracle 18c XE running inside Docker (on MacOS). I connect to it using a third party client (SQLPro Studio on MacOS). Now I want to get started.

If this were MySQL I could issue `CREATE DATABASE whatever; USE whatever;` and proceed with the tables. The same with Microsoft SQL Server, and something similar with PostgreSQL. I could also create an additional schema to keep better organised.

I gather that Oracle XE only gives you a single database, and I would want to create a suitable schema. At this point I’m at sea. I gather that I would need to create a new user associated with the schema.

I also know that different RDBMS have different ideas about what a database or a schema is, so I’m not sure whether this is the correct definition or solution.

I’m having no success creating either a new user or a new schema in my client.

I have tried:

```sql
CREATE USER fred IDENTIFIED BY 'h3art0fg0ld`;
```

but I get the message:

> invalid common user or role name

I also read that I should use something like `c##fred`, which did work, but (a) I don’t really know what that means and (b) the statement `GRANT connect, resource, create sessions TO c##printsdb;` gives me the message “missing or invalid privilege”, so I’m no further ahead.

Being in a Docker container, I don’t know whether I have access to SQL*Plus, which some online tutorials presume.

How do I create and use a schema, or whatever is required to contain a collection of tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I gather that Oracle XE only gives you a single database

Correct - as long as you "speak" Oracle-ese.

The Container Database is the only "real" Oracle Database instance that you have.

The "Pluggable Databases" *within* it are essentially "Tablespaces on Steroids", but with *much* better security that now *guarantees* the isolation of each one from every other.

For most normal operations, you should *ignore* the Container Database completely.
Just use the/a Pluggable Database inside it.

> How do I create and use a schema, or whatever is required to contain a collection of tables?
>
> CREATE USER fred IDENTIFIED BY '********';

Connect to the Pluggable Database and your statement will work exactly as you expect it to.